# How to determine if a file is a text file?

Tags: shell-script, shell

There are already [two](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208942/bash-script-check-if-a-file-is-a-text-file) [questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/172464/check-if-a-file-is-a-text-file-in-bash) on this topic here, but both address errors in their scripts rather than the actual title.

I want to develop a program that obtains some basic information about a file, depending on its type. I want to distinguish between directories, text and binary data.

So far I am using `file`:

```bsh
case "$(file --dereference $arg)" in
  *directory) ls -l --color=auto --almost-all --human-readable --group-directories-first --file-type --dereference-command-line "$@";;
  *text*|*JSON*) bat --style header "$@";;
esac
```

Which mostly works, but as you can see, I already had to add an exception for *JSON* as `file` identifies that as *JSON data* with no mention of *text*.
The problem is that there are more exceptions, and I'd prefer to not add them all individually.

Is there a way to obtain more general information on the content type from `file` or perhaps another standard program?

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation, I found a decent solution myself:

```bsh
case "$(file --dereference --mime $arg)" in
 *inode/directory*) ls -l --color=auto --almost-all --human-readable --group-directories-first --file-type --dereference-command-line "$@";;
 *binary) ;;
 *) bat --style header "$@";;
esac
```

It essentially reverses the approach - `file --mime` outputs a charset, which is *binary* for all non-text files. Then it treats everything which is not a *binary* as text, which seems to work well.

If you don't care about directories - they are also classified as binaries, so then you can use this:

```bsh
case "$(file --dereference --mime $arg)" in
 *binary) echo "$arg is not text";;
 *) echo "$arg is text";;
esac
```